# How to Read XML Multiple Tags in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, arraylist

I have a XML format stored in a String variable. It's like this,

String xml = "myXML";

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<shiporder orderid="889923"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="shiporder.xsd">
  <orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>
  <shipto>
    <name>Ola Nordmann</name>
    <address>Langgt 23</address>
    <city>4000 Stavanger</city>
    <country>Norway</country>
  </shipto>
  <item>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <note>Special Edition</note>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>10.90</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>9.90</price>
  </item>
</shiporder>
```

In above XML you can see there are multiple ITEMS. Can somebody tell using a loop or something,How can i store each Item in a arrayList or something? I would love if i can give it a try, But unfortunately i don't have an idea how to do it.

Appreciate if someone could help?

Please note that the XML is stored in the string variable as a String.

Comment: You want [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/jaxb-141136.html).  See [the official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/).

Answer (score 0):

You can parse XML pretty easily in Java.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import java.io.StringReader;

//...

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
try {
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(YOUR_XML_STRING));
    Document xml = builder.parse(is);
    Element root = xml.getDocumentElement();

    Node node = root.getFirstChild();
    while(node != null) {
        //Browse nodes
        node = node.getNextSibling();
    }
} catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
    Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.SEVERE, "Couldn't load config", e);
}
```

Note that you can also search by id or tag name for example :

```
xml.getElementsByTagName("item"); //Returns a NodeList
```

Read [the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html) for more information.

Comment: But the problem is, My XML is stored in a sting variable as a string and also how you can store it in a array List

Comment: From which part of the above code is adding the data to an arraylist

Comment: In above code node comes as null. Something is wrong

Comment: It's not adding it to an array list, but gives you the direction to make use of your XML. You can do what yo want from there. Also I'd say that using an ArrayList to store something with a tree structure is a bad idea and would make it harder to find the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ArrayList of items like below code :

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class Lab {

    public static Map<String,List<String>> hMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    public static void main(String r[]) {

        // your xml string
        String s = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "<shiporder orderid=\"889923\"\r\n" + 
                "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"\r\n" + 
                "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"shiporder.xsd\">\r\n" + 
                "  <orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>\r\n" + 
                "  <shipto>\r\n" + 
                "    <name>Ola Nordmann</name>\r\n" + 
                "    <address>Langgt 23</address>\r\n" + 
                "    <city>4000 Stavanger</city>\r\n" + 
                "    <country>Norway</country>\r\n" + 
                "  </shipto>\r\n" + 
                "  <item>\r\n" + 
                "    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>\r\n" + 
                "    <note>Special Edition</note>\r\n" + 
                "    <quantity>1</quantity>\r\n" + 
                "    <price>10.90</price>\r\n" + 
                "  </item>\r\n" + 
                "  <item>\r\n" + 
                "    <title>Hide your heart</title>\r\n" + 
                "    <quantity>1</quantity>\r\n" + 
                "    <price>9.90</price>\r\n" + 
                "  </item>\r\n" + 
                "</shiporder>";

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(s));
            Document doc = builder.parse(is);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

            for (int parameter = 0; parameter < nodeList.getLength(); parameter++) {
                List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
                Node node = nodeList.item(parameter);
                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) node;
                    String title = eElement.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent();
                    String quantity = eElement.getElementsByTagName("quantity").item(0).getTextContent();
                    String price = eElement.getElementsByTagName("price").item(0).getTextContent();

                    items.add(title);
                    items.add(quantity);
                    items.add(price);
                    hMap.put("item" + parameter, items);

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        hMap.forEach((h,k) -> {
            System.out.println(h + ":" + k);    // you can get values like hMap.get("item0") and next hMap.get("item1") etc.
        });

    }

}
```

Hope that helps you.
I have only collected common elements of item.
Hope that helps you:)